# Comparing any two objects of any data type in python

Tags: python, object, equality

I am trying to compare the values of any two objects, the datatype for which could be anything (including byte array, django objects, dictionary, boolean..... and so on). Right now I am using the '==' operator for the same. Is this the correct approach of comparing two objects?

Comment: Did you try it? If so did it give you any reason to believe it did not work correctly?

Comment: Well it works fine for the small pool of test cases I had, but I was wondering if there's any way to ascertain the same.

Answer (score 2):

'==' returns true if two objects are equal while 'is' returns true if the two variables point to the same object.
Look at this page for a more in depth explanation:
[Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python).

Are you asking how to compare two objects that are equal in value or if they are pointing at the same common object?

Comment: Your question should be a comment.